# diameter as a Morse function

Tags: co.combinatorics, at.algebraic-topology, dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, morse-theory

Consider the space $X_1$ of closed subsets not containing a pair of antipodal points of the unit circle. Here we have a kind of degenerate Morse function, defined by the *diameter* of the pointset. Namely, this is the maximal distance among pairs of points of the set. Then the extrema of the Morse function are precisely the sets of vertices of odd regular polygons, and they are in 1-1 correspondence with the connected components of $X_1$ (each odd polygon is the unique critical point in its connected component).

A similar description holds for the space $X_2$ of subsets of the unit 2-sphere, of diameter smaller than that of an equilateral triangle inscribed in the equator. Again there are infinitely many connected components, and each component contains a unique extremum. This was proved [here](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02187719). Here an extremum is of a very special "selfdual" form, e.g., its convex hull has as many vertices as faces.

It is obvious how to generalize this to $n$ dimensions but I will stick with the 3-sphere. Thus, consider the space $X_3$ of subsets of the unit 3-sphere of diameter smaller than that of the regular tetrahedron inscribed in an equatorial 2-sphere. Here again there are infinitely many connected components. Is it true that there is a unique extremum in each?

Comment: This may be a bit of a dumb question: what is the topology you are putting on $X_*$? And should the first appearance of the symbol $X_2$ be in fact $X_1$?

Comment: Also, the paper you linked to specified **finite** subsets, not arbitrary closed subsets as in your question statement, can you please clarify? (I ask because, relative to the Hausdorff metric if you allow arbitrary closed subsets I don't see how you get different "connected components").

Comment: Lastly, what do you mean by "1-1 correspondence"? What about the subset of 2 points in $X_1$? On that component there is no extrema of the Morse function, because you exclude existence of antipodal points. Similar for all even numbers.

Comment: @Willie, thanks, that was a typo and should have been $X_1$ in the first paragraph. These spaces have a natural metric defined by the Hausdorff distance between subsets, so the underlying topology is automatic.

Comment: As far as finite sets are concerned, it turns out that the minima are necessarily finite, so it does not really matter whether we consider closed sets or finite sets. For the purposes of the formal properties of the space it may be a bit more convenient to consider all closed sets (with the appropriate diameter restriction, of course).

Comment: Any two-point set (not the antipodal pair) can be naturally deformed to a single point, so it lies in the component of a single point (the "regular 1-gon").

Comment: As far as your question "I don't see how you get different 'connected components'", think of the vertices of an equilateral triangle.  This set cannot be deformed to a single point without passing through a set containing a pair of antipodal points. Therefore they lie in different components of $X_1$.

Comment: @katz: it would be better if you edited your question to incorporate these clarifications, rather than leaving them as comments.